# Perfect forwarding a member of object

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

Suppose I have two `struct`s:

```
struct X {};
struct Y { X x; }
```

I have functions:

```
void f(X&);
void f(X&&);
```

How do I write a function `g()` that takes `Y&` or `Y&&` but perfect forwarding `X&` or `X&&` to `f()`, respectively:

```
template <typename T>
void g(T&& t) {
  if (is_lvalue_reference<T>::value) {
    f(t.x);
  } else {
    f(move(t.x));
  }
}
```

The above code illustrate my intention but is not very scalable as the number of parameters grows.  Is there a way make it work for perfect forwarding and make it scalable?

Comment: I think changing `is_lvalue_reference<T>::value` to `is_lvalue_reference<decltype(std::forward<T>(t))>::value` will have the semantics you want, but I think your desired semantics are questionable...

Comment: (Sorry for the botched answer.) I'd say the reason that it doesn't scale is because the design is questionable to begin with. What does it mean to "move" a subobject? In what state does this leave the main object? Even if there were an easy way to write this, it looks like poorly structured code...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
void g(T&& t) {
  f(std::forward<T>(t).x);
}
```

Comment: @Pubby because `rvalue.foo` is an rvalue. I can think of why it may make sense (if the container has a short lifetime and is an rvalue, the contained object too shares that property), but I'm not familiar with the philosophies and don't know the rationale, so I can't say anything about it.

Comment: `rvalue.foo` should be a xvalue actauly.

Comment: @curi some committe member said so. But then what would he the reason for "rvalue" (the object expression) sometimes staying a prvalue? Against making the member selection an xvalue is the fact that its dynamic type cannot diffe from the static type of the expression.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I am looking for.

Comment: What a genius!!

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work, although I'm not sure:

```
template<class T, class M>
struct mforward {
  using type = M&&; 
};
template<class T, class M>
struct mforward<T&, M> {
  using type = M&; 
};

template <typename T>
void g(T&& t) {
  f(std::forward<typename mforward<T, decltype(t.x)>::type>(t.x));
}
```

Comment: +1 I had to solve nearly this exact problem in libc++.  The solution I came up with looked very similar to Pubby's.  Not only did I want to "apply" the l/r-valueness of `T` to `M`, I also wanted to apply the cv-qualifications of `T` to `M`.  And I found applications for it beyond data members.  For the curious, I called it `__apply_cv` and it is open source code at:  http://libcxx.llvm.org/

Comment: @Howard see my answer for an alternative. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Also @Howard talking about cv qualification makes me think about a flaw of this answer. `decltype(t.x)` only gives you the declared type of `x`. If `T` is `const`, but `x` was declared as `int a` then your forward will try to forward things as `int&` / `int&&`. You would need to say something like `typename remove_reference<decltype((t.x))>::type` to take into account the constness of `t` too. This also takes into account `mutable` members, but I don't know what move means philosophically to a mutable member of an otherwise `const` object.

Comment: @Johannes:  I agree, your solution looks better for this use case.

Comment: @Howard: What would a case look like where Johannes' solution would not work, but the `__apply_cv` one would?

Comment: @Xeo:  I used `__apply_cv` in computing the traits `make_signed` and `make_unsigned`, though in this application I'm only transferring cv-qualification and not l/rvalueness.  I also used it both in `result_of` and in `tuple_cat`.  But to be honest, these latter two uses are in such complicated code that I will stop well short of claiming that these implementations are optimal as they stand.  I would have to put an hour into studying these to be sure, and I've got to move on for now... :-)