# Perfect forwarding container element

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570655/perfect-forwarding-a-member-of-object), but instead of perfect forwarding member of an object, I would like to know how to perfect forwarding elements of an STL container, i.e. similar to

```
struct X {};
void f(X&);
void f(X&&);

template <typename Vector>
void g(Vector&& v, size_t i) {
  if (is_lvalue_reference<Vector>::value) {
    f(v[i]);
  } else {
    f(move(v[i]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Barry, I have followed to rule http://sscce.org/ to trim it to a minimum case.  The actual use case is complicated.  I'd like to create `vector<T>` from `vector<U1>`, `vector<U2>`, ...., where each element `T` is constructed from `U1`, `U2`, ....  Each array of `vector<Ui>` could be either & or &&, and I'd like the `Ui` to be perfectly forwarded.

Comment: Something like http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8aadafc70b8c979b?

Comment: @Barry The goal is to move from `v[i]` iff `v` was bound to an rvalue.

Answer (score 7):

```
namespace detail {
    template<class T, class U>
    using forwarded_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
                                              std::remove_reference_t<U>&, 
                                              std::remove_reference_t<U>&&>;
}
template<class T, class U>
detail::forwarded_type<T,U> forward_like(U&& u) {
    return std::forward<detail::forwarded_type<T,U>>(std::forward<U>(u));
}

template <typename Vector>
void g(Vector&& v, size_t i) {
  f(forward_like<Vector>(v[i]));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2751f05d8c01c089). Using `std::forward` in the implementation automatically prevents you from doing a dangerous forward of rvalue as lvalue.

For your actual use case

> I'd like to create `vector<T>` from `vector<U1>`, `vector<U2>`, ...., where
>   each element `T` is constructed from `U1, U2, ...`. Each array of
>   `vector<Ui>` could be either `&` or `&&`, and I'd like the `Ui` to be
>   perfectly forwarded.

this becomes something like

```
template<class T, class...Vectors>
std::vector<T> make_vector(Vectors&&...vectors){
    auto n = std::min({vectors.size()...});
    std::vector<T> ret; 
    ret.reserve(n);
    for(decltype(n) i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        ret.emplace_back(forward_like<Vectors>(vectors[i])...);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: So, if we have a rvalue tuple reference of lvalue references, should `forward_like<Tuple>( get_tuple_member(t) )` return an rvalue or lvalue?  I guess we cannot distinguish a "member" from a "reference member" from the accessor function.  Maybe we should be doing `std::forward<Vector>(v)[i]` and `vector::operator[]` should have an rvalue overload?  Hurm.  In theory, `std::forward<Foo>(foo).field` is what we are aiming to emulate here, no?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, so forwarding an lvalue reference member of an rvalue tuple should produce an lvalue. (I believe `std::get` already handles it?)

Comment: *nod*, but the above cannot: the only way to do that is to be "inside" the class and know if you own a `T` or a `T&`, as any sensible accessor will return `T&` in both cases.  I was just noting that if you had a (non-existent) `vector<int&>`, the above would `move`-from if the container was an rvalue, and thinking if there was a way around it.  I don't see one.  Makes `forward_like<U>` weaker than rvalue-aware accessors, fundamentally.  And rvalue-aware accessors always seemed dirty (you need to know that you aren't *really* moving, just moving that one field).

Comment: @Yakk Indeed, we'll need to know whether the thing stored is actually a reference, which means some way to query the container directly (`tuple_element_t` with tuples; perhaps `value_type` for containers).