# Function to get field value from template parameter instead of direct access to allow different names for same information

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm designing a library for internal use.

A function can be

```
template<typename It>
void doStuff(It begin, It end)
{
    // This is example code. The point is to show that I access the data of the iterator
    doStuffInternal(it->a, it->b, it->c);
}
```

This function is a template because I want to accept all kind of iterators, but I have specific expectations on the type that this iterators produce.

At the moment my code assumes an object is passed with a structure like

```
struct A
{
      int a;
      std::string b;
      BigObject   c;
};
```

I know the calling code of this function will receive data from an external API, and the data will look something like

```
struct AlmostA
{
    int a_;
    std::string _b;
    AlmostBigObject   cc;
};
```

Now I can't pass this `AlmostA` to my function and I need to convert it to `A` (or something that behaves like `A`), even if all the information are in `AlmostA`, just with different names (and slightly different types).

What I'm thinking about doing is to create a function to access the fields

```
inline int getA(const &A a)
{
    return a.a;
}

inline std::string& getB(const &A a)
{
    return a.b;
}
```

and so on for every field I need to access, then rewrite my function to be

```
template<typename It>
void doStuff(It begin, It end)
{
    doStuffInternal(getA(*it), getB(*it), getC(*it));
}
```

Then the calling code can define

```
inline int getA(const &AlmostA a)
{
    return a.a_;
}

inline std::string& getB(const &AlmostA a)
{
    return a._b;
}
```

and call my function with an iterator of `AlmostA` without any conversion.

What I hope to achieve with this is that the calling code can define how they provide the information, without being forced to have a structure with those specific fields.

I googled around and couldn't find any example of code doing this.

I'm relatively new to C++, so I'd like if this would work, what are the pitfalls of this approach, why is it not popular or not used (I know something kind of similar is done with std::swap, but that's a particular function) what are alternative solutions to present data with different interface in a unified way in the C++ world?

In what namespace does the getter function need to be implemented in order for the compiler to find them?

Comment: if what you want to do is a for each loop, you can use [std::for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) (maybe with lambda)

Comment: What is inside the function is irrelevant, that is only an example. I'm going to do operation with that data, the question is about how to provide an access to that data in a generic way

Comment: Why can't you pass `AlmostA` to your function?

Comment: @Makers_F Any generic interface/algorithm must have some requirements or `concepts`. In your case, would it be sufficient to constrain the use of `doStuff ` function to take an `iterator` whose `value_type` can be passed to `getA`, `getB` and `getC` functions AND has stream `operator <<` defined ?

Comment: Because AlmostA doesn't have a field named `a`, and thus will not even compile

Comment: What if someday you want `SetA()`? or get address of `A`?

Comment: @Arunmu my only constraint is that I'm able to get the information from the struct. The calling code might get the information from an external library it can not modify, so with the `getA` they could just provide the implementation of the function, but if I do `it->a` they will have to create a struct which has the specific interface I expect.

Comment: @appleapple good point! I only need to read the data for the foreseeable future. But in case I needed to `SetA` do you think this approach could be extended to provide that?

Comment: If the fields of the structure are not in your control, then I don't see anything wrong in general with your proposed approach. You can use `boost::fusion` to give the design a better boost (no pun intended), but as you say you are new to C++, I would probably not recommend it at this point of time.

Comment: @Makers_F of course the approach can be extended to do (almost) everything, but I would recommend keep it simple. BTW,  your `doStuff` now can not compile.

Comment: @Arunmu Basically it works like this: Layer 1( I don't control this) -- sends data in structs layer 1 defines --> Layer 2 (I do control this) --- calls ---> Layer 3 (this library I'm writing. I do control this one as well).
Layer 2 could transform every struct it gets from Layer 1 to pass it to Layer 3, but that would involve copying stuff around.
What's your opinion about transforming data vs overloading functions to abstract over the data? Do you think this approach might bite back in the future?

I'll check boost::fusion

Comment: @Makers_F I would prefer overloading functions instead of transforming data. OR you could provide both options to the user as you are developing a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `doStuffInternal(getA(*it), getB(*it), getC(*it))` seems solid to me - I would use a *`struct` template* with an *explicit specialization* for every type that you need to support.

```
template <typename T>
struct adapter;

template <>
struct adapter<A>
{
    template <typename T>
    decltype(auto) a(T&& x) { return forward_like<T>(x.a); }

    template <typename T>
    decltype(auto) b(T&& x) { return forward_like<T>(x.b); }

    // ...
};

template <>
struct adapter<AlmostA>
{
    template <typename T>
    decltype(auto) a(T&& x) { return forward_like<T>(x.a_); }

    template <typename T>
    decltype(auto) b(T&& x) { return forward_like<T>(x._b); }

    // ...
};
```

Using `decltype(auto)` as the return type and [**`forward_like`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29780197/598696) allows you to preserve the value category of `x`'s members:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(adapter<A>::a(A{})), int&&>{});

A lvalue{};
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(adapter<A>::a(lvalue)), int&>{});

const A const_lvalue{};
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(adapter<A>::a(const_lvalue)), const int&>{});
```

[**wandbox example** *(of the value category propagation)*](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IPbFZNvsx2Ck4PWO)

---

The final code will look something like this:

```
template<typename It>
void doStuff(It begin, It end)
{
    adapter<std::decay_t<decltype(*it)>> adp;
    doStuffInternal(adp.a(*it), adp.b(*it), adp.c(*it));
}
```

---

In C++11, you need to explicitly specify the return type using a *trailing return type*. Example:

```
template <typename T>
auto a(T&& x) -> decltype(forward_like<T>(x.a_))
{ 
    return forward_like<T>(x.a_); 
}
```

Comment: What are the advantages of putting the code into a specialized struct?

Comment: @Makers_F: no, you need to explicitly specify the return type with a *trailing return type*. I'll edit my question

Comment: @Makers_F: the advantages are that all getters for a specific type are "grouped together" and that you have a common type for all adapters. This can allow you to define a "concept" in the future that statically checks at compile-time whether or not a particular specialization of `adapter` has all the getters you require.

Comment: I see. So I could enable_if<adapter for it defines the methods> ?

Comment: @Makers_F: exactly. You could have a compile-time boolean `is_valid_adapter<TAdapter>` where you check that `TAdapter` implements all the required getters. Then you could either use `static_assert` or `std::enable_if` with `is_valid_adapter` to produce a nicer error message when you forgot to implement one of the getters in `TAdapter`. Another advantage is that you could also use inheritance to have some sort of "fallback" adapter type or to avoid duplication for types that have the same name for some fields.