# How to boost::bind a template member function which takes a universal reference as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, boost, universal-reference

I've been trying to use boost::bind to post a call to a member function onto an io_strand but have been getting errors. I have manged to create a simplistic equivalent example of what I am trying to do and have seen the same error in the following context:

I have the following class containing the doThings() member function I want to call:

```
class base
{
public:
  int x = 1;

  template<typename B>
  void doThings(B&& b)
  {}
};
```

There is then a subclass of this (to accurately represent the scenario I am encountering my error - I don't think it makes a difference)

```
class child : public base
{
  int y = 2;
};
```

I have the following code trying to make the boost::bind call:

```
template<typename A>
void getInt(child c, A&& a)
{
  boost::bind((void(child::*)(A)) &child::doThings, &c, std::forward<A>(a))();
}
```

And then this is being called as follows:

```
int main()
{
  child c = child();
  getInt(c, 7);
}
```

When I compile the above code I get the following error:

> error: no matches converting function ‘doThings’ to type ‘void (class
>   child::*)(int)’

---

If I change the function signature of doThings() to take a regular B type rather than a universal reference i.e.
`B` rather than `B&&` then it compiles a runs with no issues.
I suspect my issue is something to with the cast I'm doing in getInt():

```
(void(child::*)(A))
```

But I don't know what I would need to change it to. `A&&` wouldn't work in this context as I believe it would represent an r-value reference in that context. The compilation error I get when I try it seems to confirm this:

> error: cannot bind ‘int’ lvalue to ‘int&&’

For completeness: if I don't attempt to perform a cast then I get the following compilation error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(unresolved overloaded
>   function type, child*, int)’

Could someone please enlighten me on what I would need to do in order to make my boost::bind call valid in this scenario please?

I am using C++11

Comment: You know that you're passing an `int` to `doThings` right?

Comment: You might use lambda with *simpler* syntax: `[&](){ c.doThings(std::forward<A>(a));};`.

Comment: @Jonathan Mee Yes, is that an issue? 
I realize now that the getInt is an odd choice of name here - I had been messing around with various permutations for the last our or so and the fact that the function has nothing to do with getting an int has slipped through my thinking. The name is irrelevant to the intention here

Comment: Any reason to not do `c.getThings(std::forward<A>(a));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest against using `boost::bind`, as [*lambda expressions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) can be used to cleanly bind arguments *(avoiding many pitfalls of `bind` explained in [this talk by STL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt7ThwVfap0))*.

---

I'm assuming that you want to:

- **Capture `a` by move** if an *rvalue-reference* is passed to `getInt`.
- **Capture `a` by reference** if an *lvalue-reference* is passed to `getInt`.

I'm also assuming that:

- `A` is not `int` in your real code, otherwise *perfect-forwarding* would not make sense.
- You want to avoid unnecessary copies of `a` or that `A` could be a *move-only* type.
- You only have access to C++11 *(and not to newer standards)*.

If you need to *"perfectly-capture"* `a` *(i.e. capture-by-move if `A` is an rvalue-reference, capture-by-reference if `A` is an lvalue-reference)*, you need some sort of wrapper.

Unfortunately **this is non-trivial**, even though it gets better in C++14 and C++17. Here's an example of how the final syntax *could* look:

```
template<typename A>
void getInt(child c, A&& a)
{
    // `a_wrapper` stores an `A&` or an `A` depending on the value category
    // of `a`. Copying it should not copy `a` - it should conditionally move 
    // it depending on the original value category of `a`.
    auto a_wrapper = forward_capture_wrapper(std::forward<A>(a));

    // `forward_like` retains information about `a`'s value category so that
    // it can be used in the body of the lambda to forward the reference/value
    // stored inside `a_wrapper`.
    //                          vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    [&a, a_wrapper]{ c.doThings(forward_like<A>(a_wrapper.get()); }();
    //                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // `a_wrapper.get()` returns a reference that can then be moved or passed
    // to `c.doThings`.
}
```

As you can see, you need a *template function* called `forward_capture_wrapper` that deals with "perfect-capture". You can find information on how to implement that in these resources:

- [**"Move capture in lambda"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640393/move-capture-in-lambda) - covers how to implement capture-by-move in C++11. This is trivial in C++14 thanks to generalized lambda captures.
- [**"capturing perfectly-forwarded objects in lambdas"**](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/capturing_perfectly_forwarded_objects_in_lambdas.html) - this is an article I've written that covers how to implement "perfect capture" in C++14/17. It's a good starting point to understand the issue of "perfect capture" and it should be possible to convert the code to something C++11 compliant.
- [**"Capturing perfectly-forwarded variable in lambda"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831382/capturing-perfectly-forwarded-variable-in-lambda) - this StackOverflow question I asked some time ago covers some ways of implementing "perfect capture" in C++14.

By combining the resources above you should be able to implement a "perfect capture wrapper" in C++11.

You also need a `forward_like` helper function that preserves the original value category of the `a` argument. You can find an implementation of that:

- In [my `vrm_core` library](https://github.com/SuperV1234/vrm_core/blob/437a0afb35385250cd75c22babaeeecbfa4dcacc/include/vrm/core/type_traits/forward_like.hpp).
- In [this StackOverflow answer by T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29780197/598696).

Comment: Both of your assumptions are correct. Sorry, I realize my usage of int here was misleading in retrospect