# Replace multiple elements in STL map

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

I need to replace multiple values inside an `STL map` but I haven't found anything useful in `<algorithm>`.

Pseudocode:

```
Input:
    map<type1, type2> m1;
    m1[k1] = v1;
    m1[k2] = v2;
    m1[k3] = v3;


    map<type1, type2> m2;
    m2[k1] = v5;
    m2[k3] = v4;

Action:
    merge(m1, m2)

Output:
    m1[k1] = v5;
    m1[k2] = v2;
    m1[k3] = v4;
```

The `merge` method should replace `m1` values with `m2` values when keys match.

I read documentation of [merge](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/) but it seems to me not usable with maps.

Comment: `std::copy(m1.begin(), m1.end(), std::inserter(m2, m2.begin()));` will insert into `m2` elements that exist and have different value in `m1`, I guess the outcome is the same

Comment: @Piotr: your solution adds in `m2` the pair k2/v2. I tried to swap `m1` and `m2` inside `copy` but it does not work.

Comment: *"will insert into m2 elements that exist and have different value in m1"*

Comment: http://cpp.sh/6kna3 shows @PiotrSkotnicki's solution.

Answer (score 3):

C++17 adds [`std::map::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/merge), which does what you want:

> ```
> template<class C2>
> void merge(std::map<Key, T, C2, Allocator>& source);
> ```
>
> > Attempts to extract ("splice") each element in source and insert it into *this using the the comparison object of *this. If there is an element in *this with key equivalent to the key of an element from source, then that element is not extracted from source. No elements are copied or moved, only the internal pointers of the container nodes are repointed. All pointers and references to the transferred elements remain valid, but now refer into *this, not into source.

Example:

```
map<std::string, int> m1;
m1["k1"] = 1;
m1["k2"] = 2;
m1["k3"] = 3;

map<std::string, int> m2;
m2["k1"] = 5;
m2["k3"] = 4;

m2.merge(m1);

for(const auto& p : m2) 
{ 
    std::cout << p.first << " -> " << p.second << "\n";
}
```

Will print:

```
k1 -> 5
k2 -> 2
k3 -> 4
```

[**live wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/kS5q5VFNv2P2nGrq)

---

Here's a C++14 solution I came up with:

```
template <typename TMap0, typename TMap1>
auto merge(TMap0&& m0, TMap1&& m1)
{
    using map_type = std::remove_reference_t<TMap0>;

    // Move or copy `m0` into `result`.
    map_type result(std::forward<TMap0>(m0)); 

    // For each pair in `m1`...
    for(auto&& p : m1)
    {
        // If `m0` contains the key `p.first`...
        if(m0.count(p.first) != 0)
        {
            // Move or copy `p.second` into `result`.
            result[p.first] = forward_like<TMap1>(p.second);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

*([`forward_like` can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779825/perfect-forwarding-container-element).)*

Example:

```
map<std::string, int> m1;
m1["k1"] = 1;
m1["k2"] = 2;
m1["k3"] = 3;

map<std::string, int> m2;
m2["k1"] = 5;
m2["k3"] = 4;

auto res = merge(m1, m2);
for(const auto& p : res) 
{ 
    std::cout << p.first << " -> " << p.second << "\n";
}
```

Will print:

```
k1 -> 5
k2 -> 2
k3 -> 4
```

[**live wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rtaEiAaUiat702PD)

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! The short answer is: if you're not using C++17, you have to write your own loop-and-check algorithm. Am I right?

Comment: You're welcome. "Loop-and-check" is one possible solution. There very probably are different solutions that either use `<algorithm>` or use different strategies.