# C++ Copy elements from an object vector into a vector with this element

Tags: c++, vector, std

I want to copy the `a` values from the `foos` vector into another vector with just the `int` value. What's the fastest way to do this?

```
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
   int a;
};

int main() {
   std::vector<Foo> foos;
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      foos[i].a = i;

   std::vector<int> somenumbers;
   //Fastest way to copy the ints from the struct into the somenumbers vector?  

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), and then profile to make sure it is actually a bottleneck before trying to optimize it.

Comment: Whatever you do, call `reserve` on `somenumbers` before you add anything to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean fastest? Just loop, or algorithm, or something else. For example:

```
std::transform
(
    foos.begin(), foos.end(), std::back_inserter(somenumbers),
    [](const Foo& v) { return v.a; }
);
```

Also, since you know size of vector - you should call[reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).

Answer (score 3):

```
somenumbers.reserve(foos.size());
for(const auto& f : foos) somenumbers.emplace_back(f.a);
```

---

If you're doing this operation multiple times in your codebase, introduce an abstraction:

```
template <typename TRange, typename TF>
auto map_vector(TRange&& range, TF&& f)
{
    using type = std::decay_t<decltype(f(*std::begin(range)))>;

    std::vector<type> result;
    result.reserve(range.size());

    for(auto&& x : range) result.emplace_back(forward_like<TRange>(x));
    return result;
}
```

*([`forward_like` can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779825/perfect-forwarding-container-element).)*

Usage:

```
auto somenumbers = map_vector(foos, [](const auto& x){ return x.a; });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also dense/one-liner solution when you comit to using Boost:

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

const std::vector<int> extraction{
    boost::make_transform_iterator(instances.cbegin(), std::mem_fn(&Foo::a)),
    boost::make_transform_iterator(instances.cend(), std::mem_fn(&Foo::a))
};
```

The function object that is passed to `make_transform_iterator` can be a lambda, too.